# arange array result by specific key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my current array print_r

```
Array(
  [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category] => Cat1
             [title] => Title1
         )

  [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category] => Cat2
             [title] => Title2


         )
  [2] => stdClass Object
        (

            [category] => Cat2
             [title] => Title3
         )
)
```

but I need my print_r to like

```
Array(
  [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category] => Cat1
             [title] => Title1
         )

)

Array(

  [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category] => Cat2
             [title] => Title2


         )
  [1] => stdClass Object
        (

            [category] => Cat2
             [title] => Title3
         )
)
```

so I cant list all news from cat1 than cat 2 with category name on top like a accordion

```
cat1:
 Title1
cat2:
 Title2
 Title3
cat3:
 Title4
 Title5
```

any help is appreciated. thank you!

Comment: Looks like PHP, so tagged as such.

Comment: what have you tried so far? we're not here to write your code for you. we just help fix code you've already written.

Comment: i tried to output first in array like $this->list[0]  but again I get the first one from top array , also tried foreach by category key but did not work

Comment: @ jpic , it huge list , has over 200keys but here is the start    stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'id' => '24',
     'title' => 'Title1',
     'category' => 'Cat1',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
$array = array();
foreach($yourCurrentArray as $item) {
    $category = $item->category;
    if(isset($array[$category]) == false) {
        $array[$category] = array();
    }
    $array[$category][] = $item;
}
print_r($array);
```